# How to align breadcrumb

Tags: html, css

I have a a breadcrumb in my subheader however the active breadcrumb appears underneath the list. I would like it so that they are both in the same line.

HTML:

```
<div id="breadcrumb">

    <ul>            
                        <li><a href="http://test.demo.variouk.com/">Home</a> &gt;</li>          
                        <li class="active">Marketing Items</li>        </ul>    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#breadcrumb {
font-size:11px;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
}

#breadcrumb ul {
margin:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:4px;
list-style: none;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
}

#breadcrumb .active {
color:#B3B3B3;

}
```

Here is also the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4nRPY/

Comment: It's not the **active** one... try adding a third breadcrumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:left` or `display: inline-block`. But, with float left you have to clear the element right after that.

```
#breadcrumb ul li{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on your `<li>` tags

```
#breadcrumb ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4nRPY/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can this way to chive to that

```
li{float:left;}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/4nRPY/3/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a pseudo element:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/mFTGP/)

HTML

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <ul>            
        <li><a href="http://test.demo.variouk.com/">Home</a></li>           
        <li class="active">Marketing Items</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#breadcrumb ul li:after {
    content:">";
    padding:0 0.5em;
}

#breadcrumb ul li:last-child:after {
    content:"";
    padding:0;
}
```

Slighty less browser support but no extraneous HTML mark-up and you can change it throughout your site by changing one CSS property.

Comment: I would change `after` to `before` and `last-child` to `first-child`, that way IE8 will support it as well. As you might know that `last-child` is not supported by IE8, where `first-child` is.

Comment: Good point...I was in a hurry and I don't tend to worry about IE8 any more.